# PHP simulate Day Light Savings

Tags: php, timezone, dst

I have some code that handles dates and times. I think it's OK, but want to test that it works when the clocks go forwards for DST.

I can change the timezone using `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`, and wondered if there is an easy to simulate being in DST without having to wait till the clocks change!

Comment: "without having to wait till the clocks change" What about changing the system time manually?

Comment: I doubt there is an alternative to changing your system clock. What OS are you testing on?

Comment: Can test on anything other than Windows. Maybe you are right about system time, that sounds sensible as I want to check everything from a datapicker through to the database, so system = sensible.

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide details on what you want to test but I assume you have functions to do time-related stuff, e.g.:

```
function setExpiryTime(DateTime $start, $minutes){
}
```

The obvious test is to provide input parameters that will make your code cross DST boundaries. You can either find such information in your favourite search engine or run a simple PHP snippet:

```
<?php

$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
print_r( $timezone->getTransitions(mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y')), mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, date('Y'))) );
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1388530800
            [time] => 2013-12-31T23:00:00+0000
            [offset] => 0
            [isdst] => 
            [abbr] => GMT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1396141200
            [time] => 2014-03-30T01:00:00+0000
            [offset] => 3600
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => BST
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1414285200
            [time] => 2014-10-26T01:00:00+0000
            [offset] => 0
            [isdst] => 
            [abbr] => GMT
        )

)
```

Thus you can test:

```
setExpiryTime(new DateTime('2014-03-30T00:55:00+0000'), 10);
setExpiryTime(new DateTime('2014-10-26T00:55:00+0000'), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly find out, whether user is in Daylight saving zone or daylight saving is currently in effect.

```
echo date('I', time());
```

This returns 0/1; where,

> 0 = Daylight saving is not in effect.
>   1 = Daylight saving is in effect.
>
> more details : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Based on this result you can make conditional code to simulate your output.